# How to define a piecewise function with two arguments by using sympy?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

Now I have a set of values f(i,j) which distribute on the regular N*N grid. According to these grid points, I want to define a two-variate function, shown as below, and then calculate its high order antiderivative by using sympy.

[image]

For instance, [image] is the 4th antiderivative, therefore [image].

The number of grid points are 1024^2, so the Piecewise of sympy is not efficient. Can you help me?

Comment: If xi and yj are equally spaced one unit apart, then you can do something like `f(floor(x), floor(y))`. If xi and yj are defined by some function, like g(i) and h(j), then you can do something like `f(g(floor(g_inv(x))), h(floor(h_inv(y))))`. If it's something more general, then you'll have to wait for someone else to answer.

Comment: The antiderivative is just going to be something like the cumulative sum of `f(xi, yi)` plus  `mod(x)*f(floor(x), floor(y))`. Whatever your real problem is there is most likely a better way to solve it then what you're asking for in this question.